# How to implement Entity for JPA Insert/Update Entity with @OneToMany field and using composite primary

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I could not insert / update the `MaterialEntity`. But I could `findAll()` and `findById()`.

Anyone could support me?

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "material")
public class MaterialEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private Integer unitId;

    @Column(name = "transfer_unit_id")
    private Integer transferUnitId;

    @Column(name = "barcode_type_id")
    private Integer barcodeTypeId;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="material_id")
    private List<MaterialImageEntity> materialImageEntityList;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "deleted_at")
    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Integer createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Integer updatedBy;
}
```

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MaterialImageCompositePrimaryKeyEntity.class)
@Table(name = "material_image")
public class MaterialImageEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "material_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer materialId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "image_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer imageId;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Comment: To provide more specific assistance, please provide additional information about the issues you are encountering. Are you encountering any error messages? Can you share the code or steps you are using to insert or update the MaterialEntity?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set manually the inside liste, and all field before:

```
MaterialEntity materialEntity = new MaterialEntity();

MaterialImageEntity image = new MaterialImageEntity();

List<MaterialImageEntity> materialImageEntityList = new List<MaterialImageEntity>();

iterate ...
materialImageEntityList.add(image)
iterate ...

materialEntity.setMaterialImageEntityList(materialImageEntityList);

....

MaterialEntityRepository.Save(materialEntity);
```